# Integration Reportico in Yii2 Projects

Tags: yii2, reportico

I recently found out that reportico could be used to generate reports in Yii.  When creating a new report, one has to enter a specific query to produce desired results in the Query Details section. I am developing a hospital based system, and for doctors or nurses to generate reports on patients, they shouldn't write queries to generate reports. Now here is my question...  How do i integrate Reportico in my project to generate dynamic reports, that is based on user inputs and stored queries?

Answer (score 0):

I see that this was asked a while ago, but if you are still looking for an answer the [Reportico Yii2 docs](http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/embedding-reports) show how to do this.  Cut and paste the sample code under "Embedding a Report in Criteria Entry Mode" in your view.